# How to submit for with ajax and with extra fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose I have a simple form as below

```
<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
  <% if @category.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@category.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this category from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @category.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :enabled %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :enabled %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to submit this form using ajax request. Id of my form is `new_category`. So I tried something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#new_category").click(function () {  
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: '/categories',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (result) {
        return false
      },
      error: function () {
        window.alert("Something went wrong! Please try again");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is not submitting my form. I think I am missing something. Also, before submitting the form, I want to replace the name field content with a fixed string "This is a sample string". And need to send some other fixed data, such as `"user_id" => current_user.id`, "`user_name" => current_user.name`

These two fields `user_id` and `user_name`  are not in the table of category. So do I have to whitelist it in the controller? If so then how can I do that?

Comment: dont you need to send data `data:  $("#new_category").serialize()` ?

Comment: yes I need to send all data of the form, but replace the name field content with fixed string and add two more new data

Comment: There is a jquery $.ajax option `beforesend`, you can do your data modification in there

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't find the id #new_category on your form, does rails add it automatically ie framework specific? Second and most importantly, you are not sending the data parameter in your ajax settings.

as suggested by others u need to send the data as part of your ajax request. so you can add data:

to the  ajax request . Try :

```
$("#new_category").serialize()
```

So your request becomes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  $("#new_category").click(function () {  
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: '/categories',
  dataType: "json",
  data: $("#new_category").serialize() 
  success: function (result) {
    return false
  },
  error: function () {
    window.alert("Something went wrong! Please try again");
  }
});
```

});

Comment: In the html source the id showed as new_category and how can I send the data of whole form?

Comment: as suggested by others u need to send the data as part of your ajax request.

Comment: This is not sending ajax request, rather html request is being sent

Answer (score 0):

Add class or id on form and submit button like:-

```
<%= form_for(@category), id: "category_form" do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "add_category" %>
<% end %>
```

If you used devise and current_user is present then you can send extra params with form values as:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.add_category', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var user_id = "<%= current_user.id %>"
        var username = "<%= current_user.username %>"
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '/categories',
            dataType: "json",
            data: $("#category_form").serialze + "&user_id="+user_id+"&username="+username
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is not sending ajax request, rather html request is being send and so I do not get user_id and username